# Resizing script for mobile while keeping the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**I was wondering if it's possible to resize this timer for mobile while keeping all the buttons and functions working properly.**

**Here is a link to the timer:**
http://www.intervaltimer.com/timers/1566026

Here is the embed code:
    90 Seconds Circuit Timer

Create your own interval timer or download our interval timer app

var Runloop = window.Runloop || {};
    (function() {
        Runloop.defs = Runloop.defs || {};
        Runloop.defs['timer1566026'] = {"soundScheme":5,"type":3,"name":"90 Seconds","intervals":[{"name":"Rotate","duration":90,"rest":false,"music":{"PersistentId":"0","DisplayName":"No Music"},"color":0,"vibration":false}],"intervalRest":{"name":"End of interval","duration":10,"rest":true,"music":{"PersistentId":"0","DisplayName":"No Music"},"color":0,"vibration":true},"numberOfSets":10,"group":false,"setRest":{"name":"End of set","duration":15,"rest":true,"music":{"PersistentId":"0","DisplayName":"No Music"},"color":0,"vibration":true}};

```
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = '//s3.amazonaws.com/widget.intervaltimer.com/1/widget.js';
    script.async = true;
    document.body.insertBefore(script, document.body.firstChild);
})();
</script>
```

**I tried with css, I even tried to remove a couple of elements, but it never looks quite right.
Here's what I've got so far:**

/* ## Timer
--------------------------------------------- */

.seconds-timer-container { max-width: 100%;}

.seconds-timer { max-width: 100%; text-align: center !important;}

.seconds-timer, .seconds-share-options, p.seconds-interval-remaining, ul.seconds-dashboard { width: 100% !important;}

.seconds-share {display: none;}

.seconds-timer ul.seconds-dashboard li.seconds-total-elapsed { display: none;}

.seconds-reset, .seconds-start-stop, .seconds-prev, .seconds-next {width: 15% !important;}

.seconds-timer ul.seconds-dashboard li.seconds-total-remaining {display:none;}

.seconds-interval-remaining { display:none;}

**Hopefully there's someone here that can help me :) Thank you!**